# Best Way to read specific attributes in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to read this xml file in my custom object and need some help. At the end i want to create list of employee for each Record.

```
<Records>
  <Record>
     <Item NAME="EMPLOYEE NAME">
        <IValue>Henry</IValue>
     </Item>
     <Item NAME="EMPLOYEE ID">
        <IValue>321</IValue>
     <Item>         
  </Record>
      ..More Record 
<Records>
```

Employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
    public string EmployeeId {get;set;}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var employees = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring) //XDocument.Load(filename)
                    .Descendants("Record")
                    .Select(r => new Employee
                    {
                        EmployeeId = r.Elements("Item")
                                      .First(e => e.Attribute("NAME").Value == "EMPLOYEE ID").Value,
                        EmployeeName = r.Elements("Item")
                                       .First(e => e.Attribute("NAME").Value == "EMPLOYEE NAME").Value,
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: error: sequence contains no mathcing element.

Comment: @sanjeev40084 your sample xml missing closisng tags. I fixed them and used in above code. I works perfectly. Without knowing your *real* xml I can't help anymore. Just know, it is tested and works.

Comment: the xml consists of other attributes with record in addition to employee name, employee id like employee department, employee hire date etc.

Comment: @sanjeev40084 Do you expect me to guess your xml and write the code. That is all i can give as an answer. At least show some effort and try to understand what it does, How it does..

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
// Open the xml file and create the element list
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C://data.xml");
var ElementList = doc.Root.Elements();

// Crate the Employee list and populate
List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
foreach (XElement item in listaElementi)
{
   list.Add(new Employee { EmployeeName = item.Descendants().First().Value, EmployeeId = item.Descendants().Last().Value });
}
```

Descendant().First() and Descendant().Last() depend on the structure of the xml. In this way you will load your xml in memory.

If you have multiple fields to read from the xml i can propose the following solution

```
  // You need a dictionary to map the columns of the data into the property of the
  //class since they have different names.

  Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dictionary.Add("EMPLOYEE NAME", "EmployeeName");
  dictionary.Add("EMPLOYEE ID", "EmployeeId");

  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C://data.xml");
  var ElementList = doc.Root.Elements();

  List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
  foreach (XElement item in listaElementi)
      {
         // We read the properties from the xml
         var properties = item.Descendants().Where(p => p.HasAttributes);
            Employee employee = new Employee();
         // Using reflection and the dictionary we set the property value
         foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var t = property.FirstAttribute.Value;
                var s = property.Value;
                employee.GetType().GetProperty(dictionary[t]).SetValue(employee,s);
            }
         list.Add(employee);


        }
```

Comment: This is not scalable if OP adds more properties to the record.

Comment: any chances this can be based on attribute names, i got more attributes like (EmployeeDepartment, EmployeeHireDate..etc)??

Comment: edited my answer, i hope it helps.